# When uploading product image i get "upload HTTP error"

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.0.1, product-images, image-upload

When I want to upload product image I get an error:

> upload HTTP error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 7  then go to

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Find the following code

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

And replace it with

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. On server there wasn't activated **gd php extension**. I activated it and upload is now working. I hope someone would find this usefull.